# Will a Ryanair mobile boarding pass issued to non-EU citizen work? No visa check specified anywhere

Tags: visas, ryanair

I have an upcoming Ryanair flight that I have a mobile boarding pass for Malaga -> Cologne & no stipulations for a visa check, but the warnings on Ryanair website have me a bit worried. I had a visa check on my first flight (Stansted to Malaga) 12 days ago, so perhaps they do not need a follow up visa check so soon? Anyone experienced this? Wish they made it a bit more clear. I have read every Ryanair thread out there and I have seen no one in my position. Seems weird I was issued a mobile boarding pass on the app whilst being non-EU.

Album indicating difference in boarding passes: https://ibb.co/album/f2tvka

There is also no visa check stamp space on the new boarding pass. Cheers

Comment: What is your citizenship? Do you need/have a visa for Germany?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not state this but since you arrived in Malaga I am assuming you are the holder of a Schengen Visa

Your visa would be checked from the UK to Malaga because the UK is not part of the Schengen Agreement so you are traveling from a country who does not participate in that agreement to a country that is participating hence your Visa will be checked

As for your question about Malaga to Cologne since both countries are part of the Schengen Agreement your Visa will not need to be checked at every border crossing

Having a wife who is non EU citizen we have travelled Europe substantially over the years and visas are rarely checked on intra Schengen travels although it’s not unheard of.

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, Ryanair requires the extra visa check also on intra-schengen flights, although there is no official or legal requirement to do so.

Comment: Our last travel was December last year and it was not checked, having said that Ryan air is by far the most inconsistent airline in the world with regards to rules

Comment: I'm amused that the perfectly clear and straightforward answer to this Question is _perhaps_.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: To confirm what happened - I showed the ticket at the Ryanair help desk and they said no visa check specified, no visa check required. Very unclear considering their website says non-EU folks will be checked before every flight!